# How add elements in a multdimensional array on Twig?

Tags: php, twig, bolt-cms

I have this array called theme in a Twig template:

```
array:4 [▼
  "foo" => "bar"
  "headerimage" => array:6 [▶]
  "templatefields" => array:1 [▶]
  "assets" => array:3 [▼
    "css" => array:1 [▶]
    "js" => array:1 [▶]
    "libs" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "jquery"
      1 => "bootstrap"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I wanna add more elements in theme.assets.libs . I try with:

```
{% set theme.assets.libs = theme.assets.libs|merge(['otherlibrary', 'anotherlibrary']) %}
```

But I have the next error.

> Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end of statement block"
>   expected) in "index.twig" at line 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig doesn't allow doing this directly. You can instead, however, do this by continuing the pattern of array merges you're already doing:

```
{% set theme = theme|merge({assets: theme.assets|merge({ libs: theme.assets.libs|merge(['otherlibrary', 'anotherlibrary']) }) }) %}
```